# How can i build Miscord on aarch64?

Tags: android, npm, build, arm64

I am trying to build Miscord from source
(https://github.com/miscord/miscord/archive/v5.0.4.tar.gz)
on aarch64(my phone). root@kali is a Chroot enviorment on my phone. I have tested other distros((debian&ubuntu)aarch64) but no success as well. On PC amd64 starts no problem.
This is how i tried to start it. Posted the log at the bottom.
Thanks in advance!
npm was installed with

```
apt get install npm
```

Here is the commands i run:

```
root@kali:/home/kali/Miscdord# cd miscord-5.0.4/
    root@kali:/home/kali/Miscdord/miscord-5.0.4# ls
    CHANGELOG.md         Dockerfile       package.json       tsconfig.json
    CODE_OF_CONDUCT.md   Dockerfile.beta  package-lock.json  tslint.json
    config.example.json  Dockerfile.dev   README.md
    CONTRIBUTING.md      LICENSE.md       src
    dist                 node_modules     static
    root@kali:/home/kali/Miscdord/miscord-5.0.4# npm install
    
    > miscord@5.0.4 prepare
    > npm run clean && npm run compile
    
    
    > miscord@5.0.4 clean
    > shx rm -rf dist/
    
    
    > miscord@5.0.4 compile
    > tsc
    
    
    up to date, audited 518 packages in 5m
    
    10 vulnerabilities (5 low, 1 moderate, 4 high)
    
    To address issues that do not require attention, run:
      npm audit fix
    
    To address all issues (including breaking changes), run:
      npm audit fix --force
    
    Run `npm audit` for details.
    root@kali:/home/kali/Miscdord/miscord-5.0.4# npm start
    
    > miscord@5.0.4 start
    > npm run prepare && node dist/bin/index.js
    
    
    > miscord@5.0.4 prepare
    > npm run clean && npm run compile
    
    
    > miscord@5.0.4 clean
    > shx rm -rf dist/
    
    
    > miscord@5.0.4 compile
    > tsc
    
    
    Miscord should not be run with root permissions.
    If running without sudo doesn't work, you can either fix your permission problems or change where npm stores global packages by putting ~/npm/bin in your PATH and running:
    npm config set prefix ~/npm
    See: https://github.com/sindresorhus/guides/blob/master/npm-global-without-sudo.md
    If you really need to run Miscord with sudo, add parameter --runningWithSudoIsDangerous.
    
    npm ERR! code 77
    npm ERR! path /home/kali/Miscdord/miscord-5.0.4
    npm ERR! command failed
    npm ERR! command sh -c npm run prepare && node dist/bin/index.js
    
    npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
    npm ERR!     /root/.npm/_logs/2020-10-28T22_36_22_637Z-debug.log
```

Here is the log:

```
0 verbose cli [ '/usr/bin/node', '/usr/bin/npm', 'start' ]
1 info using npm@7.0.3
2 info using node@v12.19.0
3 timing config:load:defaults Completed in 2ms
4 timing config:load:file:/usr/share/npm/npmrc Completed in 3ms
5 timing config:load:builtin Completed in 3ms
6 timing config:load:cli Completed in 2ms
7 timing config:load:env Completed in 1ms
8 timing config:load:file:/home/kali/Miscdord/miscord-5.0.4/.npmrc Completed in 1ms
9 timing config:load:project Completed in 3ms
10 timing config:load:file:/root/.npmrc Completed in 0ms
11 timing config:load:user Completed in 0ms
12 timing config:load:file:/etc/npmrc Completed in 0ms
13 timing config:load:global Completed in 0ms
14 timing config:load:cafile Completed in 1ms
15 timing config:load:validate Completed in 0ms
16 timing config:load:setUserAgent Completed in 1ms
17 timing config:load:setEnvs Completed in 1ms
18 timing config:load Completed in 14ms
19 verbose npm-session 1d677a5bd581f35b
20 timing npm:load Completed in 26ms
21 timing command:run-script Completed in 250435ms
22 timing command:start Completed in 250438ms
23 verbose stack Error: command failed
23 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (/usr/share/npm/node_modules/@npmcli/promise-spawn/index.js:63:27)
23 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:314:20)
23 verbose stack     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:1021:16)
23 verbose stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:286:5)
24 verbose pkgid miscord@5.0.4
25 verbose cwd /home/kali/Miscdord/miscord-5.0.4
26 verbose Linux 4.14.117-perf+
27 verbose argv "/usr/bin/node" "/usr/bin/npm" "start"
28 verbose node v12.19.0
29 verbose npm  v7.0.3
30 error code 77
31 error path /home/kali/Miscdord/miscord-5.0.4
32 error command failed
33 error command sh -c npm run prepare && node dist/bin/index.js
34 verbose exit 77
```